# How to handle multiple image edit icons in a table with same name and id, in selenium web driver

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I have multiple edit icons in a table with same name and id, below is the html for the same,

```
  <tr class="rgRow" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_rgPatientAddress_ctl00__0">
    <td style="width:230px;">
     <span id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_rgPatientAddress_ctl00_ctl04_lblAddress"> 123 Main Street</span>
    </td><td>
   <span id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_rgPatientAddress_ctl00_ctl04_lblCity">RICHARDSON</span>
    </td><td>
   <span id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_rgPatientAddress_ctl00_ctl04_lblState">TX</span>
    </td><td>
   <span id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_rgPatientAddress_ctl00_ctl04_lblZip">75080</span>
   <span id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_rgPatientAddress_ctl00_ctl04_lblZip_Extn"></span>
  </td><td>
   <span id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_rgPatientAddress_ctl00_ctl04_lblCounty"></span>
</td><td>
<span id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_rgPatientAddress_ctl00_ctl04_lblDescription"></span>
  </td><td style="width:60px;">
 <span class="aspNetDisabled"><input id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_rgPatientAddress_ctl00_ctl04_cbPrimary" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$rgPatientAddress$ctl00$ctl04$cbPrimary" checked="checked" disabled="disabled"></span>
 </td><td style="width:60px;">
   <input type="image" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$rgPatientAddress$ctl00$ctl04$lbtnEdit" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_rgPatientAddress_ctl00_ctl04_lbtnEdit" src="../../../Images/Themes/HHM/Grey/EditIcon.png">
```

I need to edit the first row on the table.How to do it?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KaUZN.png)

Comment: Post the HTML of the entire row... from Address to Delete. You can write an XPath so that you can locate the Edit icon by street address, etc. Also post the code you have tried and the result.

Comment: @JeffC i have added the entire html of the table row..

Comment: You are missing the HTML after the `INPUT`. The table row should have a close `TR`. Also, when you post HTML please use a beautifier like https://www.cleancss.com/html-beautify/ so that it's easier to read. You also need to post your current code attempts and error message, etc. indicating how/why it's not working.